# Is $C_p - C_v = R$ valid no matter what process is done on the system?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, thermodynamics, physical-chemistry

I got this doubt because, In polytropic processes, C=Cv+R/1-n

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: This has nothing to do with a Polytropic process, which can certainly occur at low pressures where Ideal Gas behavior is involved.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That equation applies to one mole of ideal gas. It does not apply to any other physical system (unless you come up with one specially tailored to make the equation apply to it). But for the ideal gas the equation holds in all conditions. For example, it still holds when a diatomic gas has its temperature changed enough to change the heat capacities: they both change together.

Comment: +1. For completeness, perhaps you could prove these statements from the ideal gas equations of state. It would take just a few lines and would be a great example of manipulating thermodynamic terms.